# Info.plist file "no such file" error

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have tried to move the files in my project folder to a different folder and everything went ok, except that Xcode cannot find my Info.plist file now. This is the error I get.

```
could not read data from '/Users/jamiefraser/Developer/CocoaTouch Apps/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp-Info.plist': The file “MyApp-Info.plist” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file.
```

The actual files location is

```
'/Users/jamiefraser/Developer/CocoaTouch Apps/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp-Info.plist'
```

I have checked the build settings for the project and they read

```
MyApp/MyApp-Info.plist
```

I have tried deleting the build folder and cleaning the project, but I always get this same error. I appreciate any help you can offer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove MyApp/ portion from build settings. plist file usually is located in the same folder ad project. You can always open project file in vi and edit it manually.

Comment: Thanks very much. I had tried removing that before, but didn't do a clean and build afterwards. That did the trick!

Comment: Jamie, your comment about a clean helped me.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It is just a guess but it seems like one trailing `/MyApp` is too much in the location you are wanting to read from:

```
'/Users/jamiefraser/Developer/CocoaTouch Apps/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp-Info.plist'
```

As opposed to the actual location:

```
'/Users/jamiefraser/Developer/CocoaTouch Apps/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp-Info.plist'
```

It would make sense to check out the `URL` / `PATH` variable you want to read from.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after trying to duplicate and rename a project.

In Build Settings, I had to fix two paths before I finally got it compiling successfully:

- Under **Packaging**, `Info.plist`
- Under **Apple LLVM 5.0 -  Language**, `Prefix.pch`